# R rounding numbers

Tags: r

quick question, why is R rounding my "a" value?

```
> a<--2267046163.857410
> a
[1] -2267046164
> b<- 0.00050025
> b
[1] 0.00050025
```

"b" looks OK, but a is being rounded, which is causing me problems because I'm multiplying a by b and getting

```
> a*b
[1] -1134090
```

where I'm expecting to get -1134089.843

thanks

Comment: Nothing is being rounded. It's just a printing method. Try `print(a, digits = nchar(a))`  Or `print(a*b, digits = nchar(b))`. Or just for fun `options(digits = nchar(a)) ; a`

Comment: `format(a, digits = 20)` returns `-2267046163.857409954` so there's no rounding up

Comment: silly me, that's it, do you want to add it as an answer so I can accept it?
another question, if I don't like this "behavior, can I configure R or R studio to don't do it anymore? thanks

Comment: Set `options(digits =...` to whatever length you like.